# OrCAD PCB Designer Transistor Footprint

Tags: transistors, pcb, design, footprint, orcad

i want to change the position of the transistor pins (2N3904 & 2N3906, Q3,Q4,Q5 and Q7), on the first image is what i got so far (inside green oval area), the footprints are TO92.
[image]
i want to change the position of the transistor pins, something like its shown on the last image, so how i can do that ?

If i change the footprint i think i have to start over (design all the tracks, placing all components, etc, it takes again a lot of time and pacience) so if i can avoid that, that would be great.

[image]

i want to change all TO92 footprints to TO92VAR.

Comment: I don't know OrCAD PCB designer specifically, but I would be very surprised if you had to re-route your entire board just because you changed one footprint.
In AD17, you can easily change a footprint in the pcb library, and then update your existing layout to correspond with the new changes that you did. Remember to make sure that you're not changing the footprint of ALL TO92-components in your lib

Comment: You will not have to re-route the whole board, you will have to re-place and reroute those components. There are options when doing this, for instance you can have the software rip-up the etch or not. On a side note, it would have probably taken left time to actually make the change then to post it here with the mocked up drawings.  =-D.

Comment: Notice that you changed the Q3 footprint differently than you did Q4, Q5, and Q7. To do that you'll need to make two new library footprints and make sure each component is assigned the specific one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the symbol, right click and show element.  This will give you the footprint name.  Find the symbol_name.dra file in your footprint libraries.  You can either edit this one or make a copy.  Open the footprint with allegro.  Now you can edit it to your heart's content.

If you made a copy of the footprint you'll have to change the footprint name in your schematic and re-import the netlist.  If you did not go Place->update symbols.  Select package symbols and hit refresh.  It should bring them in.